# AWS : How can I get snapshots permission using boto3

Tags: boto3

I want to get value of EC2 snapshot permission using boto3.

[image]

describe_snapshots() function doesn't include the snapshot permission value, how can I get it?

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_snapshots.html

```
owner_ids = []
instances = get_describe_instances()
for instance in instances:
    print(instance['OwnerId'])
    owner_ids.append(instance['OwnerId'])

snapshots = get_describe_snapshots(list(owner_ids))
for snapshot in snapshots:
    print(snapshot)
```

Thank you.

I tried using the following functions but couldn't get any result.
describe_snapshot_attribute
describe_snapshot_tier_status
EBS resource